# Divisor group of a integral scheme of dimension one

Tags: schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne's book, for an scheme $X$ (noetherian integral separated and regular in codimension one) defined $Div(X)$ as the free abelian group generated by the prime divisors (closed integral subscheme of codimension one).

My doubt is if the definition in the Silverman`s book are the same for a algebraic curve. 
Silverman defined $Div(X)$ as the free abelian group generated by the points of $X$.

In definition of Hartshorne not include the generic point true?

Do these groups differ?

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is an algebraic curve then $X$ is a Noetherian, integral, separated scheme of finite type over a field (AKA a variety) and it's of dimension 1 (curves are $1$-dimensional).

So if $X$ is $1$ dimensional, then a codimension one subvariety of $X$ is a dimension $0$ variety which is just a (closed) point.

And, in general if $X$ is a:

- curve, then divisors are points
- surface, then divisors are curves
- 3-fold, then divisors are surfaces

Etc. We want divisors to be closed subschemes if that's what you're asking. I don't know exactly what Hartshorne says but it should just be a generalization of Silverman's definition to schemes higher dimension and not-necessarily over a field.

Comment: I have a question  @Trevor Gunn, that is my doubt principal. If $X$ is an algebraic curve then is integral and thus there exists a generic point $P$. Then  $P$ is considered for the divisor group (becasuse P is not closed) ?

Comment: Yes, the generic point is not part of the divisor group. @LuisAntonioSanchez

Comment: And the divisor group $Div(X)$ change if considered or not the generic point $P$? (i.e. the conclusion of the next theorems of Silverman's Book)

Since Silverman's book considers the group of divisors along with the generic point. For Silverman, $Div(X)$  is the free abelian group generated by the points of $X$.



This is my last doubt.

Comment: @LuisAntonioSanchez Divisors are always closed subschemes. That's the definition everyone uses, both Silverman and Hartshorne.